# Next.js | Import Module with Fs dependency

Tags: node.js, next.js, react-three-fiber

There I try to import glsl (`import glsl from "babel-plugin-glsl/macro";`), but my problem with it is that I get an "Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'" or since I configured my next.config.js - file with

```
module.exports = {
  future: { webpack5: false },
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.fallback = { fs: false, module: false };

    return config;
  },
};
```

an "Module not found: Can't resolve 'path'" - error.

I read dozens of articles and understand that the fs file is only accessible server-side and the only way to use it is in getStaticProps or getServerSideProps, but whatever I do I can't use it and really don't know or understand how to set it up so I can use it inside a component like this:

```
import { Canvas, extend } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { shaderMaterial } from "@react-three/drei";
import glsl from "babel-plugin-glsl/macro"; // <--- Module to import

const WaveShaderMaterial = shaderMaterial(
  // Uniforms
  {},              

  // Vertexshader
  glsl`            // <--- Here in Use

  `,
  // Fragmentshader
  glsl`            // <--- Here in Use
  
  `
);

extend({ WaveShaderMaterial });

const Plane = () => {
  return (
    <mesh>
      <planeBufferGeometry args={[2, 2, 16, 16]} />
      <waveShaderMaterial color="red" />
    </mesh>
  );
};

const Scene = () => {
  return (
    <Canvas>
      <ambientLight intensity={1.0} />
      <Plane />
    </Canvas>
  );
};

export default Scene;
```

My question is: How can I would or would you import glsl from "babel-plugin-glsl"(or any other module) which needs fs?

Comment: As you said: "[I] understand that the fs file is only accessible server-side and the only way to use it is in getStaticProps or getServerSideProps" - that means you can't use it in client-side code inside your React components, the library is meant to run in a Node.js environment.

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer! Yeah true, but as I mentioned, other people experienced the same problem and found a work around so they can still use it savely (at least in Next.js). Or when I read this article from https://maikelveen.com/blog/how-to-solve-module-not-found-cant-resolve-fs-in-nextjs  

"Does this mean that you cannot use such Node modules at all? No luckily not, on modern versions of Next.js (9.4+) you can safely use fs within getStaticProps or getServerSideProps, respectively used for static generation and server-side rendering. There is no extra configuration required. "

Comment: "you can safely use fs within getStaticProps or getServerSideProps" - `getStaticProps` and `getServerSideProps` run on the server-side in a Node.js environment, hence why it's usable there.

Comment: I still got hope that it is possible somehow.

Comment: Yeah I know but how do I use fs to archieve to use glsl module in getServerSideProps or getStaticProps.. I'm really confused by Next.js imports sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

I saw from the [ReadMe](https://github.com/onnovisser/babel-plugin-glsl#usage) that you can use the babel plugin [babel-plugin-macro](https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-plugin-macros/).

Create the following `.babelrc` file in the root of your project.

```json
// .babelrc
{
  "presets": [
    "next/babel"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-macros"
  ]
}
```

No need to edit `next.config.js`.

Note: Make sure you have `@babel/core` installed in your `devDependencies`.

[Here's a working example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-silence-2713x?file=/components/Scene.js)